# Polynomials generates the ideal

Tags: linear-algebra

$Hello, everyone$

Let $F$ and field $n$ positive integer. Let $g$ element $F[t]$ given by $g (t) = t ^ {n}$. Show that $g$ generates the ideal $J$ of $F [t]$ consisting of all polynomials of degree greater than or equal to $n$.

Is this statement false?

For example if n=5 then, $g (t) = t ^ {5}$ , but g(t) doesn't generate all polynomials of degee greater or equal to n, because $t^{7}+t^{6}+t^{5}-t^{4}+t^{3}-3$ doesn't be generate for $t^{5}$ or for example $t^{5}+t^{4}$ neither

How can I say that this statement is false?

sorry for the inconvenience, but my teacher said me that the statement is true and I have a lingering doubt and this is the reason for I repeated it

Thanks for you help :D Nice day.

Comment: Then edit the earlier question to indicate what it is about the answers that bothers you. DON'T just repost the same question over again. Please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Will not happen again I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You've basically got the right idea. Given a non-zero constant $\alpha$ in $F$, we have that $h(t):=g(t)+\alpha$ is a polynomial in $F[t]$ with degree at least $n$, but isn't a multiple of $g(t)$ in $F[t]$, so isn't in the ideal of $F[t]$ generated by $g$. The other inclusion doesn't hold, either, since $0\cdot g(t)=0$ doesn't have degree at least $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the statement is false. The set of polynomials of degree $\geq n$ isn't an ideal at all. Instead, $(t^n)$ consists of those polynomials whose *lowest* monomial has degree $\geq n$. For example, $t+1$ doesn't lie in $(t)$ since it has a constant term, but has degree $\geq 1$.